# Build failed due to V28 elements but target is v26

Tags: android, building

I'm trying to create a project for V26 but when I build, I get errors telling me that V28 elements are causing problems.

```
C:\Users\XXX\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\f6a183f8595ca34f3d5cc99d1f8bc322\appcompat-1.0.2\res\values-v28\values-v28.xml:5:5-8:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found
```

There is no reference to the dialogCornerRadius in the project or v28.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be you used depedencies without specifying proper version.

so change all depedencies like this

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:design:+'
```

with proper version like this

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
```

other option is to set compileSdkVersion 28 
and add two lines to gradle.properties:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```